# What is the most pythonic way to filter list of strings with a list of regular expressions in the order of the regex?

Tags: python, regex, list, filter

If I have a list of strings `strlst` and a list of regular expressions `rexlst`, what is the most pythonic way to filter out every element of `strlst` for which **none** of the regular expressions in `rexlst` matches? So, as soon as one of the regular erpressions in `rexlst` matches a string in `strlst`, this particular string, should be included in the output list. The **added complication* is, that I want **those elements of `strlst` first** that are **matched by the first regex** in rexlst, then those matched by the second and s.o.

A very simplified example:

```
import re
strlst = ['aaaaaa', '1234', 'bbbbb', '------', '.+/4-3', 'a1b2c3']
rexlst = [re.compile(x) for x in [r'^[a-z]+$', r'^\d+$']]
```

Wanted result is the outputlist:

```
outlst = ['aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', '1234']
```

It should of cause work for arbitrary combinations of any `strlst` and `reglist`. A plus is a solution that is reasonably efficient and short.

The best I could come up with is:

```
outlist = filter(lambda x: any([True if r.match(x) else False for r in rexlst]), strlst)
```

But that gives the **wrong order**, namely it preserve the order of the strings as they appear in `strlst`:

```
outlst = ['aaaaaa', '1234', 'bbbbb']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your list of strings to a `set` for easy element removal, then continuously loop over the remaining strings to see if a regex matches. You need to be careful with removing elements from sets while iterating, so make a copy each time:

```
tomatch = set(strlst)
outlist = []
for regex in rexlst:
    for value in set(tomatch):
        if regex.match(value):
            outlist.append(value)
            tomatch.remove(value)
```

This can be converted to a list comprehension but this does hurt readability:

```
tomatch = set(strlst)
outlist = [v for regex in rexlst for v in set(tomatch) if regex.match(v) and not tomatch.remove(v)]
```

These work even if strings from `strlst` match more than one regular expression.

Demo of the list comprehension:

```
>>> import re
>>> strlst = ['aaaaaa', '1234', 'bbbbb', '------', '.+/4-3', 'a1b2c3']
>>> rexlst = [re.compile(x) for x in [r'^[a-z]+$', r'^\d+$']]
>>> tomatch = set(strlst)
>>> [v for regex in rexlst for v in set(tomatch) if regex.match(v) and not tomatch.remove(v)]
['aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', '1234']
```

You are left with the unmatched strings in `tomatch`, if that is any help:

```
>>> tomatch
set(['.+/4-3', 'a1b2c3', '------'])
```